# Calling R functions from PHP and vice versa

Tags: php, r, amazon-ec2

I want to scale my set of `EC2` instances in the AWS cloud based on certain data. I want to perform this data prcoessing in R and then scale my AWS instances with `PHP SDK`. I want something like the following:[image]

I want to know what kind of APIs I can use at the `question marks`(?) in the above figure.

## EDIT

If there is no direct way of doing this, it wuld also be ok to subtitute R with any other language which can do this kind of data Analysis. At the moment, it is simple ARMA prediction, but I would like to dive deep into advanced machine learning algorithms later.

Comment: Is the R code and the php code going to reside on the same machine? I presume you could set up the R code as a console script to take input and write its output into std out or a file. You can use that information with your php script to execute your ec2 api commands.

Comment: That's one way to do it. But, I was wondering if there are any libraries/packages available which can be used to make these kind of calls, so that it would work even if the code is located on different machines. It would also be ok to substitute R with any other tool to do the data analysis.

Comment: If its on the same machine, you are going to make a system call. There are a couple different variations depending on exactly what you are trying to accomplish. Look at `exec()` and `system()`. If you are trying to run this on another machine it gets more complicated. You could connect via SSH and run the command on the remote machine or set up the code as web service (not sure what options you have for that when using R)

Comment: On your Edit. PHP is not great at data analysis at all. But there are AWS SDK packages for just about every popular language. Maybe python or java would work better?

Comment: That is a good idea. I can't change my CRON, but I can try to make the analysis part and the ec2-manager using a common language (Java/Python). However, 1 more thing I considered when choosing R is it integrates well with Tableau. This is probably off the original question, but would it be possible to integrate Java/Python analysis with Tableau.